# LVDS 30 pin cable confusion

Tags: lcd, pins, monitor, lvds, laptop

I'm trying to save a LG LM270WQ1 from a imac 2010(?)
I want to order an MT6820-B rev.3 universal LVDS driver, or kinda (because the one that is suggested for this screen is very expensive [driver suggested](https://www.ebay.com/itm/154431794070?hash=item23f4da2b96:g:2L0AAOSwwRBchjzy) and i do not even know if it will work)

The problem that I am having is with the 30-pin cable. I found the pin diagram for the monitor, and also the pinout on the MT6820-B, but the abbreviations for the outputs/inputs are *completely* different on each. I was hoping that perhaps someone might be able to help match them up so I don't fry the monitor. Once I know what goes where, I can rewire the 30 pin cable. Even if someone can help match up *some* of the wires it would be a great help.

The image below shows the LG LM270WQ1 LCD pin assignment on the left, and the MT6820-B controller on the right.

[image]
*edit: here it is in question form:

I am trying to connect the controller on the right to the monitor on the left with a 30-pin LVDS cable. Can someone please help me decipher which pins from the monitor go to which pins on the controller card?

Thanks in advance for any assistance!
(this is an improvement from another question [LVDS 30 pin cable confusion](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/239554/lvds-30-pin-cable-confusion?newreg=14e2f5baff9243ce9bd893b5493d48cd) that has been already answered, it is almost the same BUT the existence of those AUX_CH N and P are confusing me; shold it be conected to 03+-?

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE This is a Q&A style site, it appears your post does not contain a question or questions. Please edit you question and make it easier to answer by posting a question. Please visit the help center http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask for reference on posting questions. Thanks

Comment: I don't understand how the above is not considered a question?  "how do I configure the wires in the LVDS 30 pin cable from the monitor on the left to the controller on the right" in a nutshell.

Comment: @Tesseract Still not a single question mark in your "question".

Comment: First, make sure the 3.3 V/5 V selector is set to the 3.3 V position.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all set 3.3V supply voltage with jumper, as @Andrew Morton wrote in comments. Connect signals in the following manner:

1. All pins marked **VSS** on LCD (1,10,13,16 and 19) to **GND**
2. LCD supply **VDD** (pins 2 and 3) to **VCC**
3. First differential pair: **RxIN0-** (pin 8) to **O0-** and **RxIN0+** (pin 9) to **O0+**
4. Second differential pair: **RxIN1-** (pin 11) to **O1-** and **RxIN1+** (pin 12) to **O1+**
5. Third differential pair: **RxIN2-** (pin 14) to **O2-** and **RxIN2+** (pin 15) to **O2+**
6. Clock signal differential pair: **RxCLK-** (pin 17) to **OC-** and **RxCLK+** (pin 18) to **OC+**
7. Pins 4,5,6 and 7 are used for EPROM identification chip on LCD, but Your driver board doesn't use that feature, leave these lines **unconnected**, do not connect to them to GND, nor to VCC!

Comment: thank you!  so like this?  http://imgur.com/4Z0Bo2a

Comment: @Tesseract Exactly, but also connect pin number 1 from LCD to GND! If it works, please don't forget about accepting and upvote the answer.

Comment: Connect pin #1 from LCD to the GND pin on the second row  (row 2, GND/VCC)?  Or down to the ones that are 3 rows from the bottom?

Comment: @Tesseract Any GND pin should work, but I think it will be easier to connect #1 from LCD to GND pin in row 2 (pin number 4 in this case).